# Permission denied - bind(2) Errno::EACCES (Ruby on Rails, Webpack on PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, webpack

I'm trying to render my page with Ruby on Rails using the Webpacker module and a PostgreSQL database set to port 5432 (default) - I've had some back and forth with the compiler but ultimately ended up getting an Error Access. After going through my Firewall settings and ensuring that my PC is accepting connections on port 5432 (TCP) I'm still getting and EACCESS:2 error in my terminal.

I've tried switching to several unsecure networks and it's still occuring.

I'm down to thinking it's either a misconfigured Webpacker file or my Database.yml isn't set up correctly either. I'm running a RubyMine internal test environment with these settings.

```
dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 5432
    public: localhost:5432
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    compile: true
    allowedHosts: [
    'localhost',
    'localhost:3000',
    'localhost:5432']
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'
```

And this is my error log.

```
C:\Ruby26-x64\bin\ruby.exe C:/Users/Bruger/Desktop/hydac-rails/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -e development
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        22: from C:/Users/Bruger/Desktop/hydac-rails/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        21: from C:/Users/Bruger/Desktop/hydac-rails/bin/rails:4:in `require'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/server.rb:329:in `start'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:161:in `load_and_bind'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:106:in `block in parse'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:229:in `add_tcp_listener'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:229:in `new'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:229:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 5432 (Errno::EACCES)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong at this point.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what's the full name and path (relative to your rails app) of the yaml file you've listed above?

Comment: At first glance, it looks to me like you might be trying to run both your rails app and your postgres database on the same port?

Comment: The current path for my webpacker.yml file is root/config/webpacker.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to run the webpack dev server on the same port as postgresql.
I would first of all check that you have the postgesql server running on that port. Remove all references to port 5432 or urls like 'localhost:5432' from your `webpacker.yml` file above and restore the default values, something like:

```yaml
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/
```

Comment: I was running the devserver and PostgreSQL on the same port, but after checking if the server is running and making the chages you suggested, I'm getting a password authentication error. I've stated in my database.yml that my username is postgres, which is the user i created when installing the postgreSQL software, as well as the same password I used to create that user.